# Java 8 lambdas grouping by multiple fields

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have a list of pojos that I want to perform some grouping on. Something like:

```
public class Pojo {
    private final Category category;
    private final BigDecimal someValue;
}

public class Category {
    private final String majorCategory;
    private final String minorCategory;
}
```

I want a `Map<String, Map<String, List<Pojo>>>` where the key is `majorCategory` and the value is a `Map` with key `minorCategory` and values is a `List` of `Pojo` objects for said `minorCategory`.

I intend to use Java 8 lambdas to achieve this. I can get the first level of grouping done with the following:

```
Map<String, Pojo> result = list
    .stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(p -> p.getCategory().getMajorCategory()));
```

How can I now group again on `minorCategory` and get the `Map<String, Map<String, List<Pojo>>>` I desire?

**Update**

The first answer provided is correct for the example provided initially, however I have since updated the question. Ruben's comment in the accepted answer, provides the final piece of the puzzle.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
groupingBy(Pojo::getMajorCategory, groupingBy(Pojo::getMinorCategory))
```

should work, I think?

Comment: Thanks for this, this does work for the example in my question but I may have oversimplified. I'm actually grouping on a field on an object contained inside my pojo, named, say, category. I tried `.collect(groupingBy(p -> p.getCategory().getMajorCategory(), groupingBy(p -> p.getCategory().getMinorCategory())))` but it doesn't cut the mustard. Do you have any ideas?`

Comment: @RobertBain list.stream().collect(groupingBy((Pojo p) -> p.getCategory().getMajorCategory(), groupingBy((Pojo p) -> p.getCategory().getMinorCategory())));

Comment: What's the difference between all the answers.. ?